# how to create chart in jsf by FusionCharts

Tags: jsf, fusioncharts

I'm trying to create simple fusionchart in jsf.
I have a bean which can get chart JSON by method, but I could not find where should I put that.
Could you give me example, JSF2 fusion chart JSON?

Comment: i found solution.  thats all javascript.

1-Set json data to hidden input in a form in xhtml
2-get jsondata from input then assign jsondata to global js variable like that 
document.getElementById("jsonDataId").value;
3-call draw function like that:


   [code]function chartDraw(jsonData){
        var chart = new FusionCharts({
            "type": "bar2d",
               "renderAt": "chartContainer",
               "width": "500",
               "height": "300",
               "dataFormat": "json",

            "dataSource":  jsonData
        });
        chart.render();

    }
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Creating Charts using [**Fusioncharts**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/demos/chart-gallery.html) is just a matter of 10-15 mins. I have tried it several times. If you want to get a chart in JSON format it is just that you need to keep the **dataFormat** as **JSON**. One of the basic example of rendering is :

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
var salesAnlysisChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'candlestick',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '800',
    height: '600',
    dataFormat: 'json', //here the method JSON is specified
    dataSource: { /*Here you can insert the data for your chart*/ }
}).render(); });
```